# label and input width are not same with css

Tags: html, css

I have this page and its css here, i have defined same width for the label and for the input but they display in different width on the browser, why this is happening?

```css
html, body{
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 12px;
}

label{
  display: block;
  border:1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type=text]{
  font-family: inherit; //without this the font is default
  font-size: inherit; //without this the font is default
  display: block;
  border:1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="input.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>USER NAME</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="USER NAME" name="user_name"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm a beginner, so please help me.

Comment: working perfect . what is issue ? see example https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/qdfnek77/

Comment: it's working fine here, can you attach a screenshot of how it's rendering on your browser ?

Comment: But in my google chrome the inputbox is smaller than the label !

Comment: i have created the screen shot but how to add it to this comment box

Comment: I've added <!DOCTYPE html> in my html, then everything is fine. But as a leaner I would like to know why it is not working without <!DOCTYPE html> , can anyone please explain to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some browsers, default box-sizing is 'border-box', it means:

width = content width + border width + padding width

in such browsers your label is 220px

But in others,default box-sizing is 'content-box', it means:

width = content width

in such browsers your label is 200px

so just set the box-sizing for all elements:

```
*{

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;

  box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

or

```
*{

  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box ;

  -moz-box-sizing: content-box ;

  box-sizing: content-box;

}
```

set this only for label is ok too, but set for all is easy for charge

Comment: Thank you so much Chibiao Wang, I'll keep that in my mind !, Thanks everybody for taking care of my question

Answer (score 0):

Use style property "box-sizing: border-box;" for label.

```
label {
display: block;
border: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
width: 200px;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I've added <!DOCTYPE html> in my html, then everything is fine. But as a leaner I would like to know why it is not working without <!DOCTYPE html> , can anyone please explain to me ?